# Uppercase each words after space,dot,comma

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace all words first character uppercase. I can do this with ucwords but its not unicode encoding. also i need to set delimiters.

```
this is the, sample text.for replace the each words in, this'text sample' words
```

I want this text convert to

```
This İs The, Sample Text.For Replace The Each Words İn, This'Text Sample' Words
```

After comma, after dot, after space, after comma(not space), after dot(not space)

How can i convert to upper characters with **utf-8**, Thanks.

https://eval.in/485321

Comment: indirectly you want each word start with capital letter.. :D

Comment: It does not work on `'text sample'` string.

Comment: I still have encoding problem, I added the link. How can i pass these problem

Answer (score 4):

[`ucwords()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) is a built-in function for this specific problem. You have to set your own delimiters as its second argument:

```
echo ucwords(strtolower($string), '\',. ');
```

Outputs:

`This Is The, Sample Text.For Replace The Each Words In, This'Text Sample' Words`

Comment: I know, but ucwords doesn't have utf-8 encoding support.

Comment: @KadirÇetintaş It doesn't uppercase multibyte characters only. You need to replace them as you did in your code example. Check it here: https://3v4l.org/6vA8R

Comment: @Uchiha Those PHP versions are obsolete.

Comment: This worked great for me. I wanted to convert timezone into a consistent format to send to iOS and Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

For this use `mb_convert_case` with second parameter `MB_CASE_TITLE`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) like as

```
$str = "this is the, sample text.for replace the each words in, this'text sample' words";
echo preg_replace_callback('/(\w+)/',function($m){ 
         return ucfirst($m[0]);
},$str);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/485272)

Comment: However your solution fits OP problem, it's not recommended. We don't need Regular Expressions to deal with string upper-casing.

Comment: @revo Oh yes we do, especially when string-casing functions cannot perform the task.

Answer (score 1):

Not good in Regular expressions so created php function that will do what you want and if you want to add more char you can simply edit this function..

```
<?php

$str = "this is the, sample text.for replace the each words in, this'text sample' words";
echo toUpper($str);//This Is The, Sample Text.For Replace The Each Words In, This'Text Sample' Words

function toUpper($str)
{
for($i=0;$i<strlen($str)-1;$i++)
{
    if($i==0){
       $str[$i]=strtoupper($str[$i]."");
     }
    else if($str[$i]=='.'||$str[$i]==' '||$str[$i]==','||$str[$i]=="'")
    {
        $str[$i+1]=strtoupper($str[$i+1]."");

    }
}
return $str;
}
?>
```

Comment: I tryed its working but i have encoding problem. Could you please check my fork ? https://eval.in/485321

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code taken from [PHP documentation smieat's comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php#97667). It should work with Turkish dotted I, and you can add more such letters later to the supportive functions:

```
function strtolowertr($metin){ 
    return mb_convert_case(str_replace('I','ı',$metin), MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8"); 
} 
function strtouppertr($metin){ 
    return mb_convert_case(str_replace('i','İ',$metin), MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8"); 
} 
function ucfirsttr($metin) { 
    $metin = in_array(crc32($metin[0]),array(1309403428, -797999993, 957143474)) ? array(strtouppertr(substr($metin,0,2)),substr($metin,2)) : array(strtouppertr($metin[0]),substr($metin,1)); 
return $metin[0].$metin[1]; 
} 

$s = "this is the, sample text.for replace the each words in, this'text sample' words";
echo preg_replace_callback('~\b\w+~u', function ($m) { return ucfirsttr($m[0]); }, $s);
// => This İs The, Sample Text.For Replace The Each Words İn, This'Text Sample' Words
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/5M3odn)